# Compilation error while trying to call a Java method in a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, web, netbeans

Calling the parameterized constructor worked fine but when trying to call a method it showed me this error :

Cannot find symbol
Symbol: method getPassword()
Location: variable obj of type SendEmail

The Java code:

```
package Demo;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.activation.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendEmail {
   private String password = "";
   public SendEmail() {
   }

   public SendEmail(String email) {
      try {
         String randPW = this.GenerateRandomPassword();
         this.password = randPW;
         this.send(email, randPW);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error, cause: " + e);
         // TODO: handle exception
      }

   }
   
   public String getPassword() {
      return password;
   }

   public String GenerateRandomPassword() {
        String SALTCHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder salt = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (salt.length() < 18) { // length of the random string.
            int index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * SALTCHARS.length());
            salt.append(SALTCHARS.charAt(index));
        }
        String saltStr = salt.toString();
        return saltStr;
   }
   

   public void send(String email, String pw) {

      final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
      Properties props = System.getProperties();
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.debug", "true");
      props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
      props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
      final String username = "darkmotakuw@gmail.com";//
      final String password = "danewpw123%^~";
      try {
         Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
               return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
         });

         Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
         msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
         msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email, false));
         msg.setSubject("Your Password Has Arrived!");
         msg.setText(pw);
         msg.setSentDate(new Date());
         Transport.send(msg);
      } catch (MessagingException e) {
         System.out.println("Error, cause: " + e);
      }
   }

}
```

JSP code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%--<%@page import="java.sql.,java.util."%>--%>
<%@ page import="Demo.SendEmail"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <%
      String email=(String)session.getAttribute("e");
      SendEmail obj = new SendEmail(email);
      String ran_pw = obj.getPassword();
  %>
  

</body>
</html>
```

It worked fine untill I added the getPassword() method

Iam trying to get the random password generated to pass it to the DB later
Iam using NetBeans IDE 8.2

Answer (score -1):

This looks like it works OK but since you don’t do anything with the `ran_pw` inside the expression block, nothing gets displayed. You probably want a `<%= ran_pw %>` to display it.